# How to sort and handle an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array in descending order and then return the first 20 elements of that array. The following code is designed to do so however, the problem arises that when `[].slice.call(topwords).sort(function(a, b){ return b - a});` is called the array isn't ordered in descending order. When running the code through `node-debug` I can see that topwords is populated, and is populated as such:

```
"": 19
0-0: 1
1-0: 2
1-0.: 1
1-1: 1
2: 1
2/3: 1
2pm: 1
3-0: 3
3-1: 1
4: 1
4-0: 2
11am: 1
15: 1
16: 1
19:45: 1
28: 1
30: 1
30%: 2
// more of the same ...
```

I am unsure why this array cannot be sorted and then the whole of the element pushed to toptwenty to be displayed?

CODE:

```
// function for getting the frequency of each word within a string
function getFreqword(){
  var string = tweettxt.toString(), // turn the array into a string
      changedString = string.replace(/,/g, " "), // remove the array elements 
      split = changedString.split(" "), // split the string 
      words = []; // array for the words

  for (var i=0; i<split.length; i++){
    if(words[split[i]]===undefined){
      words[split[i]]=1;
    } else {
      words[split[i]]++;
    }
  }
  return words;
}

// function for returning the top 20 words from getFreqword()
function getTopwords(){
  var topwords = getFreqword(),
      toptwenty = [];

  [].slice.call(topwords).sort(function(a, b){
    return b - a
  });

  if ( topwords.length < 20 ){
    topwords = toptwenty;
    return toptwenty;
  } else {
    for (var i=0; i<20; i++){
      toptwenty.push(topwords[i]); // push the first 20 elements in topusers to the topten array
    }
    return toptwenty;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

```
[ undefined,
  undefined,
  1,
  undefined,
  1,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  1,
  1,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

What is returned when running the code.

Comment: try it the other way round: `words.sort(...).slice(...)`

Comment: `sort(function(a, b){
    return b - a
  })` only works on numbers, nothing else!

Comment: [Don't use an array for `words`](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)!

Comment: You should use comparison operator in sort. try `return a<b?-1:(a>b)?1:0`

Comment: @Bergi Why not use an array? What would be a better alternative

Comment: @Rajesh this does not affect the result

Comment: It appears that the length of topwords is 2015, but the array only has 12 elements, why isn't each instance an element in the array?

Comment: @cockmagic: Use a plain object, or even an ES6 `Map`. Arrays are only for storing integer indices, which your words clearly aren't. Also make sure the read the linked article about the problems that come with using  arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be because slice is immutable and you need to collect again, you may try this:

```
topwords = [].slice.call(topwords).sort(function(a, b){
  return b - a
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort will sort the array and update it with current one. If you wish to keep a backup, you can try something like this:

```js
var arr = ["foo", "hello", "world", "test", "abc"];

var b = arr.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
  return a < b ? -1: a > b ? 1 : 0;
});

print(arr)
print(b)

function print(obj) {
  document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
}
```